# density of  a set

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

let $S=\{\sin (n)|n \in N\}$. We can prove $S$ is dense in $[-1,1]$. So is the set $\{\sin( n^2)|n \in N\}$; but the set $\{\sin (n^3)| n \in N\}$ is not dense in $[-1,1]$. How to prove this?

Comment: Given your previous question: is this from a set of exercises? a problem in a book you are reading? a claim in a paper you are studying? Knowing these things would help people (a) decide if your question is appropriate (b) give more precise and helpful answers

Comment: Why aren't they all dense? It's just a question of whether $(n^k/2\pi)$ is equidistributed modulo 1, and that will be so for any fixed k since $\pi$ is irrational. You'd use Weyl's inequality for a rigorous proof.

Comment: As far as I remember, H. Weyl proves in 'Weyl, H. (1916). "Ueber die
Gleichverteilung von Zahlen mod. Eins,". Math. Ann. 77 (3): 313--352.' that
for each polynomial $P(n)$ with integer coefficients the sequence $exp(iP(n))$
is equidistributed in the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^{1}$\ and this implies of
course that $sin(P(n))$ is dense in $[-1,1]$. So the answer to your question
should be - no, you cannot prove this.


Answer (score 1):

If you read
[On the behaviour of $\sin(n!\pi x)$ when $x$ is irrational.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34369/on-the-behaviour-of-sinn-pi-x-when-x-is-irrational)
carefully, you will be enlightened.

Comment: how to download the Weyle'such article "Ueber die Gleichverteilung von Zahlen mod. Eins,". Math. Ann. 77 (3): 313--352.' 